# Using JQuery/JavaScript how would I group values in an array of objects and create a new array of objects from the groups

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Array of JSON objects like so

```
var dataSet1 = [{
"id": "1",
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "version": "5",
    "grade": "X"
}, {
"id": "2",
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "version": "5",
    "grade": "A"
}, {
"id": "3",
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "version": "4",
    "grade": "X"
},
{
"id": "4",
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "version": "5",
    "grade": "A"
}];
```

I would like to loop through this data set and create a new array of objects that merge the objects with similar "grade" properties and preserves a list of their associated "id" and "version" values like so

**OLD Objects with "grade" property equal to 'X'**

```
{
"id": "1",
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "version": "5",
    "grade": "X"
} 
{
"id": "3",
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "version": "4",
    "grade": "X"
}
```

**NEW Object with "grade" property equal to 'X'**

```
{
"ids":{"id":"1","id":"3"}
    "engine": "Trident",
    "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
    "platform": "Win 95+",
    "versions":{ "version":"4", "version":"5"}
    "grade": "X"
}
```

Im pretty sure I have to use the $.each and  $.grep function like so

```
    $.each(dataSet1, function (index, value) {


tsaGrade = dataSet1[index].grade;

result = $.grep(dataSet1, function (e) {
    return e.grade == tsaGrade;
})
```

and placing the ids and versions in new arrays, but I get lost on how to prevent the each loop from excluding the values that is already grouped the next time it loops through the data set.

Comment: The NEW Object is invalid as shown.  {} objects map keys to values.  Using the same key would overwrite data from the old key.  Perhaps you want to use objects containing arrays for values { "ids": [1,3] , "versions": [4,5], ...}

Comment: I'm not sure your use case, but that NEW object is going to be hard to work with. If the values don't match, you'll need to create arrays for each property (see @Paul's comment), and you'll need to keep track of indicies when you are using this object later. Your first approach is probably going to be easier in the long run.

Comment: Or the values could be objects that maintain counts of each value. Like {"ids": {"1": 1, "3": 1}} would mean I've seen id=1 once and id=3 once.

Comment: You could save your grade in a new array with the grades used and before doing the grep you can ask if the grade exists inside the array, if that is the case you continue the loop and you don't make that grep instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), this becomes pretty trivial.

Assuming `data` is your original list of json objects, this will achieve what you're after:

```
var groups = [];
var by_grade = _.groupBy(data, function(obj) { return obj['grade'] });
_.each(by_grade, function(objs, grade) {
    var group = {};
    group['grade'] = grade;
    group['ids'] = _.pluck(objs, 'id');
    group['versions'] = _.pluck(objs, 'version');
    // Use the following if the value is known to be 
    // the same for all grouped objects
    group['platform'] = objs[0]['platform'];
    // And the rest...
    groups.push(group);
});
```

`_.groupBy()` will group your objects by grade, resulting in two objects with the keys `X` and `A`, whose values are lists of objects with the corresponding grades. You can then loop over each of the two lists of objects, `pluck`ing the required values so that they will be added as lists to your new object. Difficult to describe fully, but see the log messages on this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeqeH/2/)** :)

**Edit**

Instead of `objs['platform']` should be using `objs[0]['platform']` for all attributes that you know are the same for items with the same grade.

**Edit 2**

Building from this, a better approach instead of `_.each` would probably be `_.map`:

```
groups = _.map(by_grade, function(objs, grade) {
    return {
        grade: grade, 
        browsers: _.pluck(objs, 'browser'),
        ids: _.pluck(objs, 'id'),
        versions: _.pluck(objs, 'id'),
        engines: _.pluck(objs, 'engine')
        // etc
    }
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/De5nY/1/)**